# "Parameter name cannot be empty. (CODE: 400)" whe deploying app using Deploy Azure App Service

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET Web API using Azure and "Deploy Azure App Service" task. I set variable in release:

[image]

And I set configuration inside "Deploy Azure App Service" task:

[image]

But I get this error during deployment all the time:

[image]

Could you point me in right direction as to what is wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used new task "Azure App Service Settings", then in configuration i replaced '.' with double '__', now everything works as I expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ##[error]Error: Failed to update App service 'xx' application settings. Error: BadRequest - Parameter name cannot be empty. (CODE: 400)

The cause of the issue could be that the variable value of the appsettings contains the special characters(e.g. space).

You can try adding double quotes to the variable in Azure Service Deploy task.

For example:

```
-Connectionstrings.maindatabase  "$(Connectionstrings.maindatabase)"
```

[image]